# Trying to secure Spring Web MVC using Apache Shiro where user management is achieved through Stormpath Api.

Tags: xml, spring, maven, shiro, stormpath

I am trying to secure my Spring Web MVC project using Apache Shiro and Stormpath. I went through some tutorials on the web and got an example configuration through shiro.ini file example, and also configuring Shiro through Spring's applicationContext.xml. I am trying to get the same results from both the methods. 
Here's the shiro.ini file:

> [main]
>
> shiro.loginUrl = admin/login.htm
>
> authc.successUrl = /admin/index.htm
>
> cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
>
> securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager
>
> stormpathClient = com.stormpath.shiro.client.ClientFactory
>
> stormpathClient.cacheManager = $cacheManager
>
> stormpathClient.apiKeyFileLocation =
>   $HOME/.stormpath/apiKey.properties
>
> stormpathRealm = com.stormpath.shiro.realm.ApplicationRealm
>
> stormpathRealm.client = $stormpathClient
>
> stormpathRealm.applicationRestUrl =
>   https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/
>
> stormpathRealm.groupRoleResolver.modeNames = name
>
> securityManager.realm = $stormpathRealm
>
> [urls]
>
> /admin/** = authc
>
> /logout.htm = logout

and here's the bean definations in the applicationContext.xml file:

```
 <bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>   
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/admin/login.htm"/>
    <property name="successUrl" value="/admin/index.htm"/>
    <!-- override these for application-specific URLs if you like:
    <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/unauthorized.jsp"/> -->
    <!-- The 'filters' property is not necessary since any declared javax.servlet.Filter bean  -->
    <!-- defined will be automatically acquired and available via its beanName in chain        -->
    <!-- definitions, but you can perform instance overrides or name aliases here if you like: -->
    <!-- <property name="filters">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="anAlias" value-ref="someFilter"/>
        </util:map>
    </property> -->
    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>           
            /admin/** = authc, roles[admin]
            /logout.htm = logout  
            # some example chain definitions:
            #/docs/** = authc, perms[document:read]
            #/** = authc
            # more URL-to-FilterChain definitions here
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Define any javax.servlet.Filter beans you want anywhere in this application context.   -->
<!-- They will automatically be acquired by the 'shiroFilter' bean above and made available -->
<!-- to the 'filterChainDefinitions' property.  Or you can manually/explicitly add them     -->
<!-- to the shiroFilter's 'filters' Map if desired. See its JavaDoc for more details.       -->
<!--<bean id="someFilter" class="..."/>
<bean id="anotherFilter" class="..."> ... </bean>
-->

<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
    <!-- Single realm app.  If you have multiple realms, use the 'realms' property instead. -->
    <property name="realm" ref="myRealm"/>
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>

    <!-- By default the servlet container sessions will be used.  Uncomment this line
    to use shiro's native sessions (see the JavaDoc for more): -->
    <!-- <property name="sessionMode" value="native"/> -->
</bean>
<bean id="stormpathClient" class="com.stormpath.shiro.client.ClientFactory">
    <!-- Single realm app.  If you have multiple realms, use the 'realms' property instead. -->   
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
    <property name="apiKeyFileLocation" value="$HOME/.stormpath/apiKey.properties"/>
    <!-- By default the servlet container sessions will be used.  Uncomment this line
    to use shiro's native sessions (see the JavaDoc for more): -->
    <!-- <property name="sessionMode" value="native"/> -->
</bean>
<bean id="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor"/>

<!-- Define the Shiro Realm implementation you want to use to connect to your back-end -->
<!-- security datasource: -->
<bean id="myRealm" class="com.stormpath.shiro.realm.ApplicationRealm">
    <property name="applicationRestUrl" value="https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/<my app key here removed for privacy>"/>   
    <property name="client" ref="stormpathClient"/>

</bean>

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager" />
```

I keep getting error saying:

*Cannot convert value of type [com.stormpath.shiro.client.ClientFactory] to required type [com.stormpath.sdk.client.Client] for property 'client': no matching editors or conversion strategy found*

This maybe because of incomplete maven dependency:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.shiro/shiro-spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0-RC2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.stormpath.shiro/stormpath-shiro-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.stormpath.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>stormpath-shiro-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0-RC1</version>
</dependency>
```

Can someone suggest the dependencies required to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be missing the [factory-bean / factory-method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.9/reference/beans.html#beans-instance-factory-method) elements in your XML.

On a side note, the easiest way to get started with Apache Shiro and Stormpath is to take a look at one of the [examples](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-shiro/tree/master/examples)
In your case probably the [spring-boot-web](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-shiro/tree/master/examples/spring-boot-web) one.

Using Spring's auto configuration via the [`shiro-spring-boot-starter`](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-shiro/blob/stormpath-shiro-root-0.8.0-RC1/examples/spring-boot-web/pom.xml#L44-L47), you should only need to worry about your [method annotations](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-shiro/blob/stormpath-shiro-root-0.8.0-RC1/examples/spring-boot-web/src/main/java/com/stormpath/shiro/spring/boot/examples/AccountInfoController.java#L33).

Comment: Could you please look at this issue please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584523/apache-shiro-xml-based-configuration-gives-null-pointer-exception-for-dao